# Bounties are being listed twice on profile page

Tags: bug, bounty, profile-page

[image: On this screenshot one can see 2 bounties being offered at the same time for the same question by the same user, of the same amount of rep. Clearly, it looks like a bug.]

That's how my "bounties" tab looks like now. It seems like my current [bounty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78967/which-dragon-magazine-issue-did-this-unusual-rat-like-race-appear-in) is being shown twice (as my previous bounty on the same question was made a bit earlier than 5 hours ago).

Comment: Holy tab-explosion, Baskakov-man!